# What are the Attributes for the Reserved DeDupe Rules

Tags: duplicate-contacts

The reserved dedupe rules don't tell us what they are doing behind the seens. The name and email (reserved) rule says:

> This reserved rule is pre-configured with matching fields to optimize
>   dedupe scanning performance. It matches on:
>
> 1. Email
> 2. First Name
> 3. Last Name

But it doesn't reveal the length, weight or threshold?

I'm kind of assuming that all three have to match exactly for civi to not create a duplicate record (unservised) or for it to not pop-up a duplicate warning (supervised).

Am I correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the DB I can see that dedupe_rule_group_id 1 (in civicrm_dedupe_rule) has following rows

`id dedupe_rule_group_id    rule_table  rule_field  rule_length rule_weight
    1   1   civicrm_contact first_name  NULL    5
    2   1   civicrm_contact last_name   NULL    7
    3   1   civicrm_email   email   NULL    10`

and from civicrm_dedupe_rule_group we have 'threshold = 20'

`id contact_type    threshold   used    name    title   is_reserved
1   Individual  20  Supervised  IndividualSupervised    Name and Email (reserved)   1`

ie
First 5
Last 7
Email 10
Threshold 20

BUT - Jon points out that this is just a useless remnant from our evolutionary past so take his answer as the valid one.

Comment: This is the common-sense answer, but there's a special case at work here.  Be glad you haven't had cause to find out the truth the hard way!

Answer (score 5):

Pete's answer should be correct, but reserved dedupe rules don't work like normal rules.  The original assumption: First name, last name and email must all be identical - is correct.

Dedupe rules with multiple criteria work by running a separate query for each criterion, filling a temp table with the weights.  This is flexible but inefficient, so the "reserved" queries are done using a single handwritten SQL query.  This particular query is found in `CRM_Dedupe_BAO_QueryBuilder_IndividualSupervised::internal` and overrides the stored query in the database (which is the old query from before reserved queries existed).  Here's the query that runs.

```
        SELECT contact1.id as id1, contact2.id as id2, {$rg->threshold} as weight
        FROM civicrm_contact as contact1
          JOIN civicrm_email as email1 ON email1.contact_id=contact1.id
          JOIN civicrm_contact as contact2 ON
            contact1.first_name = contact2.first_name AND
            contact1.last_name = contact2.last_name
          JOIN civicrm_email as email2 ON
            email2.contact_id=contact2.id AND
            email1.email=email2.email
        WHERE contact1.contact_type = 'Individual'");
```

Comment: Thanks Jon - I edited mine, but could delete if it makes more sense.