# Dedupe rule not working for Email only

Tags: dedupe-rules

CiviCRM 5.39.0/Wordpress 5.72

When adding a new Individual in backend, the Email only Dedupe rule doesn't work. When I enter the email address, no other data, of a known contact, it does not find the duplicate. If I enter the First Name, no other data, it finds duplicates. First and Last Names also work, but Email alone doesn't work. Using original rules. I want the de-duplication rule to work when only the Email is entered. What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot of Rules]

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. i just set up Email only as the Supervised rule on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and had the same outcome. I will raise on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/

Comment: I haven't confirmed but think this is still true: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/16336/181. I.e. that if your rule of a given type is marked reserved then it doesn't matter what it's called or the settings, it uses an internal function. So you would need to make a NEW rule with email only that isn't the reserved one and mark it supervised. I think.

Comment: Unfortunately adding a new Email Only Supervised rule doesn't work either.